# TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable, error when creating an trading bot with python

Tags: python, json, trading, metatrader5

I am creating a trading bot. I have 2 files a settings.json file and a main.py file.

my settings.json file :

```
`{
    "username": "51410030",
    "password": "s5p3GI1zY",
    "server": "Alpari-MT5-Demo",
    "mt5Pathway": "C://Program Files/Alpari MT5/terminal64.exe",
    "symbols": ["USDJPY.a"],
    "timeframe": "M30"
}
```

and my main.py file :

```
import json
import os
import mt5_interface
import strategy



# Function to import settings from settings.json
def get_project_settings(importFilepath):
    # Test the filepath to sure it exists
    if os.path.exists(importFilepath):
        # Open the file
        f = open(importFilepath, "r")
        # Get the information from file
        project_settings = json.load(f)
        # Close the file
        f.close()
        project_settings = list(project_settings)
        # Return project settings to program
        return project_settings
    else:
        return ImportError


# Main function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Set up the import filepath
    import_filepath = "C:/Users/james/PycharmProjects/how_to_build_a_metatrader5_trading_bot_expert_advisor/settings.json"
    # Import project settings
    project_settings = get_project_settings(import_filepath)
    # Start MT5
    mt5_interface.start_mt5(project_settings["username"], project_settings["password"], project_settings["server"],
                            project_settings["mt5Pathway"])
    # Initialize symbols
    mt5_interface.initialize_symbols(project_settings["symbols"])
    # Select symbol to run strategy on
    symbol_for_strategy = project_settings['symbols'][0]
    # Start strategy one on selected symbol
    strategy.strategy_one(symbol=symbol_for_strategy, timeframe=project_settings['timeframe'],
                          pip_size=project_settings['pip_size'])
```

my prblem is when i run my main.py file it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "i:\Traiding Bot\code\main.py", line 32, in <module>
    mt5_interface.start_mt5(project_settings["username"], project_settings["password"], project_settings["server"],
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

please help me.

I couldn't find a solution please help me.

Comment: are you sure, you want to do `project_settings = list(project_settings)` ... try removing list

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work.

Comment: may I know why you are returning `ImportError`?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. You're trying to access fields in a list. That's not possible, you should keep your list a dictionary if you want access its fields.
2. You're returning an ImportError, if you want to raise an error, use `raise ImportError("Your error message")`. Or if you want to catch the error, use a `try: <your code> except: return None` and then check if you're returning None or not.